# How to receive Key Event from other App? [C++. Windows.h.]

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I'm making a macro program that drags and drops and comebacks to drag-starting point process.
I designed it to work like this:

- "MyMacro" is my program.
- "3DMax" is an app I'm using.
- (RC) is "Ctrl+Spacebar + Right click" input to setup drop-point.
- (LC) is "Ctrl+Spacebar + Left click" input to activate the macro.

  1. In "3DMax", I do (RC) on trash-can. 
     By doing (RC), my computer sends the cursor position information to "MyMacro". 
     That information is drop-point.
  2. In "3DMax", I do (LC) on a unnecessary 3D Object. 
     By doing (LC), my computer sends CURRENT Cursor Position to "MyMacro".
     That information is original-point.　And then it runs macro which is "Hold Left Click - Move cursor to drop-point - Release Left Click - Comeback to original-point".

I just learned WM_KEYDOWN, but it doesn't run the event when "MyMacro" is not activating. I want this program to function even when it's minimalized.

I learned how to SEND keyinput to other program, but I don't know how to REICEVE keyinput from other program.

**How can "MyMacro" get keyinput from other program so that it gets information without activating the window?**

I don't expect to get full code for this, I just want to know the keyword that I can search and look deeper. Please help.

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question. You do realize that two different applications can communicate directly? Data can be passed through using shared memory etc.

Comment: Shared memory isn't intended for routine IPC